# TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...).connect is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, next.js

I'm trying to connect to my MongoDB database. I've imported mongoose as follows:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
```

When I try to connect to my MongoDB database using `mongoose.connect(...)`, it returns an error:

> [TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...).connect is not a function]

I'm writing my code in Next.js. The database connection function is called in the middleware script (not frontend). Here are my scripts:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connect = async() => {
    try {
        mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://root:toor@capxlogicsh.neqdpxf.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Database connected!");
            })
    } catch(err) {
        console.error("Something went wrong connecting to database");
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Middleware:

```
export const middleware = async (request: NextRequest) => {
    await database.connect();
}

export const config = {}
```

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

---

I'm very much stuck on this, and couldn't find real answers online. I've tried a bunch, mostly suggesting the import of mongoose should be different, which I've tried. These I've tried:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import mongoose = require("mongoose");
import { connect } from 'mongoose';
```

---

Anyone that has a solution for this?

Comment: Just ran into this issue as well. It was working fine for me and then suddenly stopped.

Comment: @dangtony98 I've found out myself that you can't connect to MongoDB through the middleware on Next.js. That was what fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

I am using next.js 14 and was getting the same error while using server actions and trying to connect to my database.

I just had to use
`"use server"`
at the top of the file from where I am calling the `connectToDatabase` function.

Spend my whole day on this